# Is it possible to find such consecutive numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Is it possible to find 99 consecutive natural numbers if the first one must divide by 100, the second one must divide by 99, the third one must divide by 98 and so on. The last number must divide by 2.

Comment: The first such sequence starts at 69720375229712477164533808935312303556700

Comment: @HenningMakholm Great! How did you get this number?

Comment: Wait please, now I don't get it. We require that n+100 is divisible by 100, 99, 98, etc. That means n should be divisible by 100. So we must find a number $n$ so it doesn't divide by 99, 98, 97, 96, etc (not including the divisors of 100)?

Comment: @Raffaele I think it is computed by coding.

Comment: @Raffaele: Trial and error? No, I multiplied together all the primes less than $100$, with enough additional factors of $2, 3, 5, 7$ to cover their powers less than $100$ ... and then subtracted $100$. The reasoning behind this is covered by Lord Shark's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first one is $n$, then $n+100$ is divisible by $100$, by $99$, by $98$ etc. Can you find a suitable $n+100$?

Comment: Why should n+100 be divisible by 99 and by 98 at the same time?

Comment: @A.Ben: Because you are requiring that $n+1=(n+100)-99$ is divisible by $99$, and $n+2=(n+100)-98$ is divisible by $98$.